# Phonon VideoPlayer c++ example

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

I want create video player in Qt 4.7.0. And i find Phonone lib.
I'm find example in documetation, but if i take I have crash

Code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    VideoPlayer *player = new VideoPlayer(VideoCategory);
    player->setFixedSize(QSize(400,300));
    player->move(1280-400,0);
    player->show();
    connect(player, SIGNAL(finished()), player, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    player->play(MediaSource(QString("C:\\vid.flv")));

}
```

Error:

```
debug/mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow':

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:16: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11VideoPlayerC1ENS_8CategoryEP7QWidget'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceC1ERK7QString'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11VideoPlayer4playERKNS_11MediaSourceE'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceD1Ev'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceD1Ev'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:16: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11VideoPlayerC1ENS_8CategoryEP7QWidget'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceC1ERK7QString'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11VideoPlayer4playERKNS_11MediaSourceE'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceD1Ev'

C:\Qt\2010.05\videoPlayer-build-desktop/../videoPlayer/mainwindow.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Phonon11MediaSourceD1Ev'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe somebody know what is it?

Comment: Perhaps your linker is [having trouble finding the library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: thx add 
Qt += phonon